# adjusting position of a div based on its previous div, which is rendered dynamically

Tags: html, css

I am having two div's next to each other, first one will be rendered on Ajax call and will be filled with more content, so its content height is not known.

I want the second `div` to always appear at the bottom of first div regardless of the first div's height, I mean: after the Ajax call rendering completes, the second `div` should be positioned immediately under the first `div`.

Will something like this work?

Note: I am not applying the below CSS. I gave it as an example.

```
.seconddiv
{
    position: relative;
    top:  (top of first + height of first);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to set anything.
this is the default behavior of block elements: to be stacked one after each other.

sometimes, less is more.

Here is a [**Working Snippet**](http://jsbin.com/ojIfogo/1/edit?html,css,js,output) for you to try. [notice the empty **CSS** panel except outlining, that is for you to see that the positioning works]

Comment: yes i know as the first will keep increasing as per the rendered html the second is not staying in the right position it overlaps with first

Comment: that means you gave the first or second div some position styling. you should remove everything. as I said.. what you wand is the pure default style. post your code so I can fix it for you.

Comment: make sure both divs have their position property set to static

Comment: you don't have to do this. static is the default positioning value. don't write code if it's not needed.

Comment: @avrahamcool He has obviously overriden the default positioning value, otherwise he would be getting the results he expects.

Comment: the **CSS** `position` attribute is [not inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). so default is always `static`. he don't have to explicitly write it. he should just not write something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

keep the position of the dynamically generating div as static

```
position:static
```

Now give the position property for next div as absolute

```
position:absolute
```

and then give your "top" or "margin-top" whichever you are trying with

Comment: `static` is the default value of `position` it doesn't have to be written. as for the second `div`, absolute positioning him will force you to set his position (via `top`&`left`). this is completely unnecessary.